# I want to use pull to refresh on a Listview that is built from a Riverpod Model provider that gets it's data from a Future Provider

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

```
   body: Container(
            child: Consumer(builder: (context, watch, child) {
              var wallet = watch(walletBuilderProvider);
              //print(wallet.allWalletItems[0].eventName);
              return WalletList(wallets: wallet.allWalletItems);
            }),
          )
```

```
final walletBuilderProvider =
    ChangeNotifierProvider.autoDispose<WalletModel>((ref) {
  final walletData = ref.watch(dataProvider);
  // Create an object by calling the constructor of WalletModel
  // Since we now have memory allocated and an object created, we can now call functions which depend on the state of an object, a "method"
  final walletModel = WalletModel();
  walletModel.buildWallet(walletItems: walletData);
  return walletModel;
});
```

What I do initially to refresh all the data before it loads is I just call

```
context.refresh(dataProvider);
    context.refresh(walletBuilderProvider);
```

Here is the List that gets called to display the data.

```
class WalletList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Wallet> wallets;

  WalletList({required this.wallets});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: wallets.isEmpty
            ? Container(
                height: 150,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "List is empty",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            : getWalletListItems());
    // return ListView(
    //   children: getWalletListItems(),
    // );
  }

  ListView getWalletListItems() {
    print(wallets.length);
    print("afterwallets");
    var walletList = wallets
        .map((walletItem) => WalletListItem(wallet: walletItem))
        .toList();
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: walletList.length,
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          double scale = 1.0;
          return Opacity(
            opacity: scale,
            child: Align(
                heightFactor: 0.7,
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                child: walletList[index]),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

What I want to do in the end is use some form of RefreshIndictator to refresh both providers but when I have been attempting to implement that in either the Consumer or the WalletList I haven't been seeing any change at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `walletBuilderProvider` watch `dataProvider` so you only need to refresh `dataProvider`, that will force a refresh on all providers that depend on it

Have you tried using `RefreshIndicator` Widget?

```
RefreshIndicator(
   onRefresh: () async => context.refresh(dataProvider),
   child: WalletList(wallets: wallet.allWalletItems),
);
```

Comment: That didn't work and the progress indicator never showed up when I used that code.

Comment: Your code worked. I had a mistake in my physics. For anyone else having this issue look into your ListView.builder. I needed to change my physics to  physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),